# Exporting text from Excel to PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, export, powerpoint

I am writing a VBA code to create a PowerPoint from an Excel document.  I have the PowerPoint opening and my text exporting, but am running into a syntax issue because I want to export text and not a table, bitmap, picture, etc.

I have tried the following syntax and am running into errors.

First:

```
slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
```

(along with all other possible "ppPaste..." options)

Second:

```
slde.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=100, Height:=100)
```

This one gives me errors with the dimensions even when I've copied someone else's working code to test it out.

Is there a better way to export text?
Thank you.

Code:

```
Sub ExporttoPPT()

    Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim slde As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shpe As PowerPoint.shape
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Dim vSheet As String
    Dim vRange$
    Dim vWidth As Double
    Dim vHeight As Double
    Dim vTop As Double
    Dim vLeft As Double
    Dim vSlide_No As Long
    Dim expRng As Range
    
    Dim adminSh As Worksheet
    Dim cofigRng As Range
    Dim xlfile$
    Dim pptfile$
    
    Dim pptapp As Object
   
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set adminSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPTPage")
    Set cofigRng = adminSh.Range("Rngsheets")
    

    pptfile = adminSh.[pptpth]
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)
    
    '---set variables
    For Each Rng In cofigRng
    
        With adminSh
            vSheet = .Cells(Rng.Row, 3).Value
            vRange$ = .Cells(Rng.Row, 4).Value
            vWidth = .Cells(Rng.Row, 5).Value
            vHeight = .Cells(Rng.Row, 6).Value
            vTop = .Cells(Rng.Row, 7).Value
            vLeft = .Cells(Rng.Row, 8).Value
            vSlide_No = Cells(Rng.Row, 9).Value
            Debug.Print vSheet
            Debug.Print vRange$
            Debug.Print vWidth
            Debug.Print vHeight
            Debug.Print vTop
            Debug.Print vLeft
            Debug.Print vSlide_No
        End With
        
    '---export to ppt
            
            wb.Activate
            Sheets(vSheet).Activate
            Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet).Range(vRange$)
            expRng.Copy
            
            Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)
            
            slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
            slde.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
            Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=100, Height:=100)
            
            
            Set shp = slde.Shapes(1)
            
            With shp
                .Top = vTop
                .Left = vLeft
                .Width = vWidth
                .Height = vHeight
        
            End With
        
        Set shp = Nothing
        Set slde = Nothing
        
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set expRng = Nothing
    Next Rng
    
    Set pre = Nothing
    
    
    'wb.Close False
    'Set wb = Nothing
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For straight text, it's better to use something like ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Textframe.TextRange.Text. Please post your code, so we can see the context.

Comment: In addition to JohnK's request, please quote the *exact* text of the error message you're getting. Also, what happens if instead you use 
Call slde.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=100, Height:=100)

Comment: For the slde.shapes.pastespecial my text is exported to the powerpoint but it is not in the location on the slide and/or on the slide number I told it to be on.  I get a combination of incorrect location and slide number depending on what I put after .pastespecial.  For the "(Orientation:=msoTextOrientation Horizontal)", I get a compile error that says "Expected: =". I will post my code below for more context and will play around with the ActivePresentation.Slides(1)... John mentioned.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Either remove the parentheses after AddTextbox or leave it as it but put CALL in front of it, as suggested.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Adding "Call" no longer gives me an error(sorry I didn't see you added that in the first comment).  New issue though, the text box is there but it's empty... I feel like I'm missing a line of code to tell it what text to export.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found this: ".TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test Box" " being an option to add to the end of the "Call slde..." line, but I'm getting an error with that again.  It's shown as going after the close parentheses.  Let me know if you know any syntax for that function.  Thank you!